# Why there is no such a thing as colour moment?

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, dipole-moment, confinement, color-charge

I was busy google about different types of electric and magnetic dipole moment then a thought suddenly striked me, why there is no colour multipole moment?

Comment: What would that be or what would it describe (differently)?

Comment: Who says there isn't one?

Comment: why don't you google "color dipole" ?